# Travis CI fails to rsync (ssh) with publickey, but same command works in terminal

Tags: ssh, yaml, travis-ci, rsync, ssh-keys

I'm setting up automated deployment with TRAVIS CI, but my script gets stuck when trying to rsync to my server. From what I can tell, it's the SSH login that's failing, specifically the publickey login.

My YAML file (`User`, `Host`, `Dir` and `Key Decryption` (openssl aes--256-cbc etc...) replaced) :

```
language: node_js 
node_js:
- 10.7.0 
addons:
  ssh_known_hosts: <HOST>   
  hosts: <HOST> 
branches:   
  only:
  - master 
env:   
  global:
  - DEPLOY_USER=<USER>
  - DEPLOY_HOST=<HOST>
  - DEPLOY_DIRECTORY=<DIR> 
before_install:
- npm install -g npm@6.4.1 
install:
- npm install 
script:
- npm run build 
before_deploy:
- <DECRYPTION> -in deploy_rsa.enc -out /tmp/deploy_rsa -d
- eval "$(ssh-agent -s)"
- chmod 600 /tmp/deploy_rsa
- ssh-add /tmp/deploy_rsa 
deploy:   
  provider: script   
  skip_cleanup: true   
  script: rsync -r --delete-after --quiet -e"ssh -v -i /tmp/deploy_rsa" $TRAVIS_BUILD_DIR/dist/ <USER>@<HOST>:<DIR>   
on:
  branch: master
```

Everything works fine until the rsync, which gives this log (again, hostname, user and ECDSA key replaced here) :

```
Deploying application
OpenSSH_6.6.1, OpenSSL 1.0.1f 6 Jan 2014
debug1: Reading configuration data /home/travis/.ssh/config
debug1: /home/travis/.ssh/config line 1: Applying options for *
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to <HOST> [127.0.0.1] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /tmp/deploy_rsa type -1
debug1: identity file /tmp/deploy_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_6.6.1p1 Ubuntu-2ubuntu2.8
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_6.6.1p1 Ubuntu-2ubuntu2.8
debug1: match: OpenSSH_6.6.1p1 Ubuntu-2ubuntu2.8 pat OpenSSH_6.6.1* compat 0x04000000
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: server->client aes128-ctr hmac-md5-etm@openssh.com none
debug1: kex: client->server aes128-ctr hmac-md5-etm@openssh.com none
debug1: sending SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_INIT
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: ECDSA <ECDSA>
debug1: Host '<HOST>' is known and matches the ECDSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /home/travis/.ssh/known_hosts:11
debug1: ssh_ecdsa_verify: signature correct
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering RSA public key: /tmp/deploy_rsa
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug1: Trying private key: /tmp/deploy_rsa
debug1: key_parse_private2: missing begin marker
debug1: read PEM private key done: type RSA
<USER>@<HOST>'s password: debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug1: Next authentication method: password
```

When I try the same rsync command from my own machine (with the same publickey and a test folder), it works and gives this :

```
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: deploy_rsa
debug1: Authentication succeeded (publickey).
Authenticated to <HOST>.
```

I've scoured documentation, searched far and wide, tried a lot of different things already, different ways to add the key to the ssh-agent, specifying it manually, sudo true/false/required, etc... and i'm at a loss.

I'm noticing slight differences of log, the TRAVIS log seems to think my server accepts password authentications, whereas my own machine's log shows only "publickey" as a valid method, which is correct since password authentication is disabled.

The ssh-agent correctly tries to give the key in /tmp/deploy_rsa, which for some reason fails, then I manually give it, it shows `key_parse_private2: missing begin marker` (which from my searching seems to be a normal message indicating a successful passwordless login?) and seems to fail again.

Would there be a way to make TRAVIS understand that password login is disabled? To force the ssh-agent to only use publickey ? And why does it seemingly retries (tries key from ssh-agent, tries my key, etc...) but is not showing any failure messages, the key seems recognized and valid.

Possible the decrypted key (deploy_rsa) is not valid ? the same key, before encrypting with `travis encrypt-file deploy_rsa --add` works on my machine.

Thank you in advance for your answers.

Comment: It gives the IP address of `<HOST>` as 127.0.0.1, which is probably not what you wanted.

Comment: Wow. Thank you, it didn't accept domain names, it needed the IP. I feel stupid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well it turns out Travis CI doesn't want domain names (even though this works in every other context for me), and absolutely needed the IP address.

I tried it but had other earlier problems (decrypting private key) and forgot to try the IP once those were fixed.

I feel silly, but now it works.